# Are all Refactorings parameterized?

Tags: refactoring, parameterized

The question is about refactorings. Consider a rename method refactoring. This refactoring can be visualized as meta-method that takes old and new names, and changes the old method name to the new. so, for refactoring

foo()
{
.........
.........
}

to

boo()
{
.........
.........
}

the meta method for refactoring would be ...

renameMethod (foo, boo)

This is called parametrized refactoring. My question is can all refactorings mentioned in http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/ be thought of as having some parameters or are there refactorings that do not need such parameters?

Answer (score 2):

There are some "code cleanups" which don't require parameters. Whether you'd call them refactorings or not I don't know, but:

```
if (condition) {
    return firstValue;
} else {
    return secondValue;
}
```

to:

```
return condition ? firstValue : secondValue;
```

or even more so:

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

to:

```
return condition;
```

But even within the "proper" refactoring catalog there are some which don't require parameters. For example, the [hide method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/hideMethod.html) refactoring just makes a method private, and ["reduce scope of variable"](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/reduceScopeOfVariable.html) just moves a declaration.